# Why do I get the "No path to find" error in XML::XPath?

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to run a Perl file I created.

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

# create an object to parse the file and field XPath queries
my $xpath = XML::XPath->new( filename => shift @ARGV );

# apply the path from the command line and get back a list matches
my $nodeset = $xpath->find( shift @ARGV );

# print each node in the list
foreach my $node ( $nodeset->get_nodelist ) {
  print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string( $node ) . "\n";
}
```

When I run `perl xmlfile.pl` I get this error

```
"No path to find at /usr/lib/per5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/XPath.pm line 65"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program expects command-line arguments, first the file name and then an XPath expression. [`@ARGV`](http://p3rl.org/var#%40ARGV) is the hint. Try:

```
perl xmlfile.pl ex07_xpathdata.xml '//item'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting

```
perl xmlfile.pl file.xml /some/xpath
```